# Is the naught in $x_0$ an ordinal?

Tags: terminology, ordinals

I'm making a spreadsheet containing basic physics terms, symbols, units, defining equations, and a simple English translation of the defining equation. I learned these things in high school, but I'm starting from scratch so that I can make sure I have a better sense of more advanced equations.

For example:

```
  Var       Name                  Unit   Defining Equation                Logical Meaning               
 ----- --------------- --------- ------ ------------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  _₀    initial ___     ordinal   none   _ₙ, where n = 0     ___ at the start                           
  Δr    displacement    vector    m      Δr = r - r₀         change in spatial position in a direction  
  Δt    time interval   scalar    s      Δt = t - t₀         change in temporal position
```

I know my characterizations of displacement as a vector and time interval as a scalar are correct, but is it technically correct to call the n in x<sub>n</sub> an ordinal? Or, is there a better descriptor for this?

It's not essential for my spreadsheet, but now I'm really curious.

Comment: Well, ordinals assign an order, so I would imagine the answer is yes.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Indices are most commonly natural numbers, and the role they play in that case is precisely ordering.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would say it is *not* an ordinal. When you use, say, $v_0$ to denote the initial velocity, the $0$ subscript is just a decoration used to denote the initial value of a quantity. If we wanted to, we could instead have used some other convention (for example, $v_\ast$).

An alternative setup is to have $v_t$ denote velocity at time $t$. But it would be quite unusual to describe a continuous parameter as an ordinal.

Lastly, when we have a discrete sequence of values $x_0, x_1, x_2, \dots$, we can describe $x_n$ as "the $n$th value". In this case, it makes sense to describe the subscripts as ordinals, though even in this situation the word "index" is generally the one used.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer for which I was looking. I took logic as my "quantitative analysis" credit at Uni mainly because my understanding of maths immediately dissolved in high school trig. So, can you please explain how indices differ from ordinals?  

Logically, I would think an index could be built of something other than numbers, such as letters, geometric symbols, or even hieroglyphics whereas an ordinal would have to be numerical. But, I'm only guessing and don't know the technical semantics.